# How to assign a value to an observable when the statevector is not an eigenvector of the operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, linear-algebra, eigenvalue, observables

We get the value of an observable $A$ for a given state $|\lambda\rangle$ of a system from the eigenequation $\hat{A} |\lambda\rangle = \lambda |\lambda\rangle$ where $\hat{A}$ is the operator corresponding to observable $A$ and $\lambda$ is the required value of the observable. But this is true only when the statevector $|\lambda\rangle$ is an eigenvector of the operator $\hat{A}$. How do we assign a value to observable $A$ when the statevector $|\lambda\rangle$ is not an eigenvector of the operator $\hat{A}$?

I am a beginner in quantum physics with elementary understanding of linear algebra so please try to answer accordingly.

PS: [This](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/348732/how-does-a-linear-operator-act-on-vectors-that-are-not-eigenvectors-of-the-opera) question is related and its accepted answer is helpful. But from it I could not understand how to assign a value to the observable.

Comment: Thank you @Ghoster for the edit!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How do we assign a value to observable $A$ when the statevector $|\lambda\rangle$ is not an eigenvector of the operator $\hat{A}$?

**We don't.**

One of the toughest parts of learning quantum mechanics is learning to let go — in particular, learning to let go of the requirement that everything must have a value. In QM, if you have a system in a given state $|\psi⟩$ and a given observable $\hat A$ representing a physical quantity $A$, the generic setting is that the system *cannot* be assigned a value for $A$.

In some lucky occasions, of course, it turns out that $A$ does have a well-defined value (and these are, as you'll have guessed, when $|\psi⟩$ is an eigenstate of $\hat A$).

But, in general, observables in quantum mechanics do not have value until and unless a projective measurement of that observable is performed on the system.

Comment: According to answer of @Arturodonjuan, we can find average value of observable when the state vector is not eigenvector of operator. I assume that both answers spell truth with different perspectives. But then I can't reconcile both answers. Can you please explain on that line?

Comment: The 'expectation value' of $A$ in the state $|\psi⟩$ is what you get if you take the system in the state $|\psi⟩$ and then (i) perform a projective measurement of $A$, which will then (ii) change the state of the system to one of the eigenstates of $\hat A$ and produce the corresponding eigenvalue as the value of $A$, and then (iii) you repeat this procedure multiple times (typically on a large ensemble), which will then typically (iv) give a wide spread of different values of $A$ with different frequency; and then finally you (v) take the average of the value of $A$ over this distribution.

Comment: However, this does **not** mean that the expectation value of $A$ is in any way assignable as "the value of $A$ prior to the measurement". That value does not exist, and cannot be assigned.

Comment: I get your point that there is an 'expectation value' but don't get that it is not assignable as a value of $A$ prior to the measurement. I think, even the definite outcome given by the eigenvalues too is what we get after measurement. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but you need to actually perform the measurement (and therefore destroy the state) for any of those values to be realised. If you try to talk about the results of measurements that are not actually performed, you very quickly get into counterfactuals that you cannot get out of.

Comment: So we can conclude that when the state vector is an eigenvector of the operator, we get a definite outcome which is one of the eigenvalues. When the statevector is not an eigenvector, it is a linear combination of the eigenvectors as answered @Arturodonjuan. As a result of measurement, the statevector collapses to one of the eigenvectors and we again get a definite value corresponding to the state after collapse. We can assume an expectation value which is average of all possible values of measurement (eigenvalues).After measurement, however, the measured value would be one of the eigenvalues.

Comment: Yes, those statements are all correct. Whether you want to think of any of those quantities as "the" value of $A$ prior to the measurement is ultimately an unanswerable subjective question, but long experience has taught that trying to do so leads very quickly to epistemological trouble, so within standard QM those values are not assigned. Many people have tried to extend/break QM to change this, and hopefully some day someone (maybe you) will succeed, but I would argue that by the time that's done, the resulting theory will no longer be QM but something else.

Comment: Thank you for helping with insightful answers.

Answer (score 2):

A pure physical state is comprised of a linear sum of eigenstates:

$$|\psi\rangle = \sum_{i} c_i |\lambda_i\rangle$$

where $|\lambda_i\rangle$ are complete eigenstates of a self-adjoint operator $A$, $\langle \lambda_i |\lambda_j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$ and $\sum_i |c_i|^2=1$.

The probability that we will find $|\psi \rangle$ in the $|\lambda_i\rangle$ state (i.e. having value $\lambda_i$ when acted upon by operator $A$) is given by $|\langle \lambda_i | \psi\rangle|^2=|c_i|^2$.

The average value of the operator $A$ in the state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by $\langle \psi | A |\psi \rangle = \sum_i |c_i|^2\lambda_i$. This is the average value of $A$ you would measure if you prepared an infinite number of identical systems described by the state-vector $|\psi\rangle$.

Comment: Is there a reason for saying a state as 'pure' physical state?

Comment: Yes because a physical state is in general described by as a 'mixed' state, represented by a density matrix/operator. A special case is when the physical state/system can be represented by a single state vector, i.e. it is a 'pure' state. See [the wikipedia article here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix).

Comment: Can you explain in the post, or point me to an easy to understand online resource, why the average value (expectation value) is as you have written?

Comment: @Aarone Do you mean why the expectation value of an observable $\hat A$ in a physical state $|\psi\rangle$ is given by $\langle \psi | \hat A |\psi\rangle$? This is sort of by definition, an axiom of the framework of quantum mechanics. With this, the relation $\langle \psi | \hat A |\psi\rangle = \sum_i |c_i|^2 \lambda_i$ follows by direct substitution of $|\psi\rangle = \sum_i c_i |\lambda_i\rangle$, and using that the set of eigenstates $|\lambda_i\rangle$ is orthonormal, i.e. $\langle \lambda_i |\lambda _j\rangle = \delta_{ij}$.

Comment: I was asking about how $\langle \psi | \hat A |\psi\rangle$ is equal to $\sum_i |c_i|^2 \lambda_i$. Your hint is sufficient. Thank you.

Comment: My query is solved by reading answers of both you and @Emiliopisanty but I could accept only one answer. Anyway, thank you again very much for your great answers!